# How to vectorise an integration function?

Tags: numpy

I'm a beginner in numpy and I want to vectorise this function:

[image]

I don't quite understand what I need to do but this is what I've come up with:

```
n = 1000000
h = 1/n
x = np.arange(1,n,1)

def f(x):
    return x ** 3

def rec(x):
    result = np.zeros_like(x)
    result[x < n] = f((x[x < n])*h)
    return result

integral = 0.5*h + h*rec(x)

print integral
```

I end up with an array of 0's. Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
def trap(f, a, b, n):
    xs = np.linspace(a, b, n + 1)
    ys = f(xs)
    return (0.5 * ys[0] + 0.5 * ys[-1] + np.sum(ys[1:-1])) * (b - a) / n
```